# Start new process without waiting for all other processes to finish

Tags: python, multiprocessing

If I start multiple processes like this:

```
        procs = []
        for agent_id in agents:
            proc = Process(target=beginmultiproc, args=(id))
            procs.append(proc)
            proc.start()

        # wait for processes to finish
        for proc in procs:
            proc.join()
```

Is there a way I can start a new process as soon as one has finished, rather than needing to wait for all to finish?  I want to run 8 processes at a time as that's how many cores my CPU has, but I have more than 8 jobs that I need to run, so as soon as one process has finished I want to start the next process running.

I'm aware of `pool.map` but I can't use it in this case.

Comment: you would need to define some constraints of when to stop forking and not go into infinite process generation. Preconditions are required.

Answer (score 2):

You could also take a look at [ProcessPoolExecutor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#processpoolexecutor) which, if I remember correctly, is built on top of multiprocessing and provides a somewhat simpler way of doing things.

Alternatively, check [concurrent futures](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.as_completed) which has an "as_completed" method which will yield results as each process completes allowing you to work with those values immediately.

Answer (score 1):

You do not have more processes than 8. You have more "work-items/tasks" than 8. Use a `multiprocessing.queue` to schedule your work. If a process is idle get something from this queue and process it until the queue is finished. You do not have to kill processes and spawn another one.

Comment: You're right, my use of 'processes' in that context was wrong, changed my wording to 'jobs'.  I will investigate using queues, that sounds to be what I'm after.